# Get Email of User Authenticated in Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication

My Azure Web App written in Node.js is authenticated with the Azure Active Directory and logs in users with their Microsoft Account. I'd like to know the emails of logged in users, and tried to make http get request to `/.auth/me` endpoint on the client side and server side. However, my last attempt on the server side, I get a 401 code: `"{\"code\":401,\"message\":\"IDX12741: JWT: '[PII is hidden]' must have three segments (JWS) or five segments (JWE).\"}"`.

I made sure to included the `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie in my request to the endpoint, and am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't have Azure Function enabled, so this is why I'm relying on http requests.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getstuff(req, res);
});

var getstuff =  function (request, response, next) {
  console.log(request);
  console.log("getting stuff");
    var token = request.cookies.AppServiceAuthSession;
    console.log("my token is ", token);
    var options = {
        hostname: 'webportal.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/.auth/me',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'x-zumo-auth': token // <-- is this the right field name? 
        }
    };
    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log("inside auth me request");
        var str = '';
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            str += d;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log("ended ");
            console.log(str);
            response.status(200).type('application/json').json(str);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
    });
    req.end();
}
```

Comment: Is that your application is nodejs express web app application?

Comment: Besides, could you tell me how you configure Azure AD auth?

Comment: yes it's a web app. Basically I went to Authentication and toggled on app service authentication

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? if you have no other concern, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppServiceAuthSession` is cookie which is different than a token. If you want to retrieve access token, we need to update the config of Azure app auth settings to make it acquire the access_token for the web API.

Regarding how to configure it, please refer to the following steps

1. Login to [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com)
2. At the top of the page, select **Read/Write**.
3. In the left browser, navigate to **subscriptions** > **<subscription_name >** **resourceGroups** > **<resource_group_name>** > **providers** > **Microsoft.Web** > **sites** > **<app_name>** > **config** > **authsettings**.
4. Click **Edit**.
5. Modify the following property. Replace <app_id> with the Azure Active Directory application ID of the service you want to access.

```
"allowedAudiences": [
      "<app id>"
    ],
"additionalLoginParams": ["response_type=code id_token", "resource=<app_id>"]
```

After that, you can use the `req.headers["x-ms-token-aad-access-token"]` to get token and call API

For example

```
const express=require('express')
const request = require('request');
const router =express.Router()

var app = express()
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
 
 var token = req.headers["x-ms-token-aad-access-token"]
  
     getstuff(token).then(response => {
       console.log(response)
      res.json(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
          res.send(error)
      })
    
  });
  
  var getstuff =  async function (token) {
    
    console.log("getting stuff");
    
   
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://testnodeweb06.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me',

  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token
  }
};
console.log(options)
return new Promise(resolve => {
  request( options,  function (error, response, body) {
     if(!error){
       console.log(body)
      resolve(JSON.parse(body));


     }
        
  });
  
 
});

  }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, how do I find the Azure Active Directory application ID? Do I need to register the app?

Comment: I followed your instructions but there is no property ""x-ms-token-aad-access-token"" in my headers

Comment: @ILike Is that you have updated your app service auth settings and you still can not see the headers? Besides, could you please tell me which application id you use? Is application id of the application you use to configure app service authentication?